# How to get items from collection by ids

Tags: mongodb, kmongo

I am passing a `List<String>` that are item ids in a request. I need to get only items that ids are in a list. Basically, I send you a list of product ids and MongoDB should return a `List<Product>`. I thought it would be something built in, but I cannot achieve it.

I have tried something with aggregate, evaluate etc., but I cannot find a way. I thought it could be as simple as:

```kotlin
override suspend fun getProductsById(input: List<String>): List<Product> {
    return productsCollection.aggregate<Product>(
        match(Product::_id in input)
    ).toList()
}
```

There is no way in my understanding, but I must be wrong as this, I assume, is like a core feature that a simple API should allow.
Probably I could just do a 2008 style with looping through a `List<String>` and just requesting a product one by one with:

```kotlin
productsCollection.findOne(Product::_id eq itemId)
```

However, I don't think I should run several requests, this seems as a very wrong idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with:

```
productCollection.find(Product::_id `in` ids)
```

The `in` keyword is reserved for the for loop.

Comment: Correct, thank you, I have found out a while ago about exactly that. What was unclear for me is how to use bson filter infix fun and I was using regular in instead of `in`. Thanks anyway! :) 

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Iterable-